# How to redirect and pass parameter at the same time in Perl?

Tags: perl, redirect, cgi

I am having a hard time figuring out how to redirect to another page and at the same time to pass a parameter in Perl. I tried the CGI.pm library and Perl books but all I can find there are examples of just redirecting without any additional parameters. What I am trying to do is redirect to another page if user entered the right password, but I want to display his name on the other page so I tried:

```
$cgi->redirect('myothersite', value="username");
```

and in the other site I tried to get that value with:

```
$cgi = CGI->new;
$username = $cgi->param("username");
```

or

```
 my %name = map { $_ => 1 } param;

    if ($name{username}) {
      my $username  = param("username");
      print   
          header,
          start_html,
          "Hello, $name",p,
          etc...
```

and all kinds of other ways of making it work but that just gives me errors. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just include the parameter in the query string:

```
$cgi->redirect("myothersite?username=$username");
```

Alternatively, you can save the key/value in a [`CGI::Session`](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session) or similar construct.

Comment: thanks but in the other file it prints it as $username and not as the name that $username stands for, how do I get the actual name out of it?

Comment: I tried retreiving it with:  my $cgi = CGI->new; my $un = $cgi->param("username");  and then using $un in my code, so it just prints $username and not the name that was stored in $username 0n the other page.

Comment: actually, I was using single quotes in my redirect and when I switched to double quotes everything worked. Thanks again.